# Alternatives to joins in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a query as follows that retrieves the status for different stores in a table and displays it as different columns.

```
SELECT a.Store_ID,b.total as order_completed,c.total as order_cancelled,d.total as order_processed,e.total as order_failed FROM ORDER_HISTORY a
    -> LEFT OUTER JOIN(select Store_ID,count(*) as total from ORDER_HISTORY where Status = 57 group by Store_ID)b on a.Store_ID = b.Store_ID
    -> LEFT OUTER JOIN(select Store_ID,count(*) as total from ORDER_HISTORY where Status = 53 group by Store_ID)c on a.Store_ID = c.Store_ID
    -> LEFT OUTER JOIN(select Store_ID,count(*) as total from ORDER_HISTORY where Status = 52 group by Store_ID)d on a.Store_ID = d.Store_ID
    -> LEFT OUTER JOIN(select Store_ID,count(*) as total from ORDER_HISTORY where Status = 62 group by Store_ID)e on a.Store_ID = e.Store_ID
    -> group by a.Store_ID;
```

Can anybody suggest an alternative to using joins as it affects the performance of db operations.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an index on `ORDER_HISTORY` over `(Store_ID, Status)`, then this should be *plenty* fast.

```
SELECT
    Store_ID,
    status,
    COUNT(*) as total
FROM
    ORDER_HISTORY
GROUP BY
    Store_ID,
    status;
```

Then use your application to display the few resulting rows data in columns. Should not be hard to implement.

---

Another approach would be (same index as above):

```
SELECT
    Store_ID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 57 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS order_completed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 53 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS order_cancelled,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 52 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS order_processed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 62 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS order_processed
FROM
    ORDER_HISTORY
GROUP BY
    Store_ID;
```

Replace NULL values as appropriate.

Comment: @Tomalak-I need an output as below.Please help!
| Store_ID | order_completed | order_cancelled | order_processed | order_failed |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+
|       20 |              99 |              34 |            NULL |         NULL |
|     2502 |               2 |            NULL |            NULL |         NULL |
+----------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------------+

Answer (score 0):

Try using a trigger. Same as a stored procedure that executes when an event occurs within the database. maybe it will help you.